# How to add file in an pre-request script using form data on Postman

Tags: file-upload, multipartform-data, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to create a request in the pre-request script using in the form-data and in the body i would like to upload a pdf file from my working directory.

I used the following script and the file is not attached in my script.
Can you please help me to identify my problem?

```
"body":{ 
        "mode": "formdata",
        "formdata": [
            { "key" : "file","value": "X:\\Postman\\files\\test.pdf", "disabled" : false, "description" : {"content" :"", "type" :"file"}},
            { "key" : "text","value": "text", "disabled" : false, "description" : {"content" :"", "type" :"text"}},
            { "key" : "Number","value": "12345686", "disabled" : false, "description" : {"content" :"", "type" :"text"}},
            { "key" : "Text","value": "0011002327", "disabled" : false, "description" : {"content" :"", "type" :"text"}},  
            { "key" : "Date","value": "02/12/2020", "disabled" : false, "description" : {"content" :"", "type" :"text"}}
        ]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the request body via Postman's pre-request script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715532/how-to-set-the-request-body-via-postmans-pre-request-script)

Answer (score 0):

In case of file, KEY name should be **src** instead of value

eg- `"src": "X:\\Postman\\files\\test.pdf"`

otherwise it will treated as a text not as file path

[kindly refer screenshot for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZxak.png)